Finding a value $n$ such that $\sqrt[n]{x^{x^{2}}} \le x^{\sqrt[n]{x^{2}}}$ is true.
For what value of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the following inequality is true.
$$\sqrt[n]{x^{x^{2}}} \le x^{\sqrt[n]{x^{2}}}$$
Where $0<x\le \sqrt[5]{216}$
ATTEMPT:
This is my first time tackling a problem like this so I wouldn't say I did much but firstly I try to take logarithm of both sides to see what happens...
$(x^{x^{2}})^{\frac{1}{n}} \le x^{(x^{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$
Taking log yields,
$\frac{x^{2}}{n}\log(x) \le x^{\frac{2}{n}}\log(x)$
At this point split into $2$ cases, one where $0<x<1$ and the other is $x \ge 1$. For the former I got that:
$\frac{x^{2}}{n} \ge x^{\frac{2}{n}} \implies x^{2} \ge nx^{\frac{2}{n}}$
Now I'm not so sure where to go from here, any hints?

Huh...the book I'm reading this problem from says that $n=6$ is also a solution, I can't seem to see that though

Hint: can you go further and rearrange $x^2 \ge nx^\frac{2}{n}$ so that you have only expressions involving $x$ on one side and only expressions involving $n$ on the other?

Wouldn't I just get $\log(x) \ge \frac{\log(n)}{2-\frac{2}{n}}$?

If I continue from where, you have been, then from your comment, I have:
$$
\log(x)\geq\frac{\log(n)}{2-\frac{2}{n}}
$$
This can further be written as:
$$
x\geq n^{\frac{n}{2n-2}}
$$
Here, as $0<x<1$, then a condition is $n\neq1$. Therefore, for the next natural number, if we set $n=2$, we find the R.H.S. to be $2$, that does not satisfy the condition $0<x<1$. So, there lies no solution in this zone.
Secondly, for the other condition, we have $x\geq 1$ and all the same mathematical computations lead to the inequality, that
$$x\geq n^{\frac{n}{2n-2}}$$
Since $0<x\geq \sqrt[5]{216}$ or $0<x\geq 6^{\frac{3}{5}}$. Now, we can write:
$$6^{\frac{3}{5}}\geq n^{\frac{n}{2n-2}}$$
By comparing, we can set $\frac{n}{2(n-1)}=\frac{3}{5}$ and arrive at $n=6$. The solution $n=1$ is not possible from this calculations. Perhaps, it is from:
$$x^2\geq nx^{\frac{2}{n}}$$
where $n=1$ satisfies the problem.
